# avm.sty not properly formatting in beamer

Tags: beamer, linguistics, avm

I'm putting together a presentation that includes HPSG attribute-value matrices. The matrices that work well in plain document LaTeX however are not rendering correctly in Beamer. When the file is compiled, all the attributes are lower-case. Everything else looks fine. I can go through manually adding \textsc{} to everything but this is a bit tedious. Is this a known issue with a resolution?

I've determined that it isn't an errant package being included. Below is the code for a minimal repro with an example basic avm.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
}

\usepackage{avm}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{HPSG Matrix}

\adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{
\begin{avm}
\[\asort{some-raising-type}
synsem.local.cat.val & \[ subj & \< \[ local.cont.hook.index & \avmbox{1} \] \> \\
      comps & \< \[ local & \[ cat.head & verb \\
      cont.hook.xarg & \avmbox{1} \] \] \> \] \]
\end{avm}
}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this compiles properly with `article`? I get the same output.

Answer (score 2):

The default setting for the font style is empty. You need to tell `avm` explicitly what style you want using the `\avmfont` command, in this case `\avmfont{\scshape}`

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
}

\usepackage{avm}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\avmfont{\scshape}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{HPSG Matrix}

\adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{
\begin{avm}
\[\asort{some-raising-type}
synsem.local.cat.val & \[ subj & \< \[ local.cont.hook.index & \avmbox{1} \] \> \\
      comps & \< \[ local & \[ cat.head & verb \\
      cont.hook.xarg & \avmbox{1} \] \] \> \] \]
\end{avm}
}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]